# How to write a single JSON from multiple JSON files with dictionary?

Tags: python, json

I have many json files (upto 1000) and data format in every json file is like below

```
[[0, -0.1, -0.2, 0.7], [1, 0.7, -0.1, 0.5], [2, -0.4, -0.8, 0.9]]
```

I'm trying to save data from all json files into one json file in dictionary. I have almost done but the problem is that data is saving only from first json file. Below is my code.

```
# load all json files from folder
json_data = []
    for r, d, f in os.walk('data'): # folder where all json files exist
        for file in f:
            if file.endswith('.json'):
                json_data.append(os.path.join(r, file))

    for f in json_data:
        with open(f, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f) 
        #print(data)  # if I print 'data' then I'm getting data from all json files. Means all files are loaded successfully

# data in dictionary with required arrays arrangements 
output_dict = {
        'data_1' : data[1],
        'data_2' : data[2],
        'data_3' : data[0]
}

# save new json file
with open('final_data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump([output_dict], f)
```

The only problem is that I'm getting data from first json file loaded from folder, even all files are loading.

Furthermore from every array of main list I want to remove first index value, like in above exmaple I don't want value `0` from first array, value `1` from second array and value `2` from third array, all these values are at zero index of each array in main list of every json file.
The new json file will be as

```
[{"data_1": [-0.2, 0.7, -0.1], "data_2": [-0.1, 0.5, 0.7], "data_3": [-0.8, 0.9, -0.4]}, {second_file_data_from_json_file}, {third_file_data_from_json_file}....]
```

Looking for some kind suggestions as I'm unable to find solution for my problem.

Comment: instead of `data = json.load(f)` you could try `data[<my_filename>] = json.load(f)`. I would also change `with open(f, 'r') as f:` to not use the same `f` variable

Answer (score 3):

You never put the data into any bigger structure. You overwrite your `data` and only the last one "survives".

```
json_files = []    # names of files
json_data = {}     # dictionary for data from files, key is filename

for r, d, f in os.walk('data'): # folder where all json files exist
        for file in f:
            if file.endswith('.json'):
                json_files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for fn in json_files:
    with open(fn, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f) 
        json_data[fn] = data

# save new json file
with open('final_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f)
```

should put your dictionary to your new json file. If you need different keys, change this too your liking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're always re-using the same `data` variable to store the most recent content of your json files as a string.

What you want to do is define `data` as a list (like you did with `json_data`) and then instead of

`data = json.load(f)`

write

`data.append(json.load(f))`

You probably also want to dynamically build `output_dict` in case you ever have more/less than 3 json files in your diretory.

E.g.:

```
output_dict = {}
for idx, val in enumerate(data):
    output_dict['data_{}'.format(idx)] = val
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your second for loop with below and remove data assigning to the dictionary which is "after data in the dictionary with required arrays arrangements" comment

```
output_dict = {}
i = 0
for f in json_data:
    i = i + 1
    key = "data_{0}".format(i)
    with open(f, 'r') as fp:
        output_dict[key] = json.load(fp)
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop is likely the main issue. You are overwriting `data` on each iteration.

```
for f in json_data:
        with open(f, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
```

You'll want to do something like this:

```
data = []
for f in json_data:
        with open(f, 'r') as f:
            data.append(json.load(f))
```